# Finding Differences between Queries glitch?

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access

I have a series of queries and for some reason, when I do my final one, it switches all of the names in that field to numbers that are not the key from its table or anything that I can figure out. I am finding the difference between queries and then union'ing them together to see the total amount of differences between the two sets.

```
 SELECT [MD/SA].[MD/SA Number], Junction.[Part Number], Junction.Quantity, 
 Junction.Designator
 FROM [MD/SA] INNER JOIN Junction ON [MD/SA].ID = Junction.[MD/SA Number]
 WHERE ((([MD/SA].[MD/SA Number])=[Insert Number 1:]));
```

Dif1^

```
 SELECT [MD/SA].[MD/SA Number], Junction.[Part Number], Junction.Quantity, 
 Junction.Designator
 FROM [MD/SA] INNER JOIN Junction ON [MD/SA].ID = Junction.[MD/SA Number]
 WHERE ((([MD/SA].[MD/SA Number])=[Insert Number 2:]));
```

Dif2^

```
 SELECT Dif1.[MD/SA Number], Dif1.[Part Number], Dif1.Quantity, 
 Dif1.Designator
 FROM Dif1 LEFT JOIN Dif2 ON Dif1.[Part Number] = Dif2.[Part Number]
 WHERE (((Dif2.[Part Number]) Is Null));

 MD/SA Number    Part Number            Quantity    Designator
 MD1907201B      B32674D6105K           2   C1, C2
 MD1907201B      DEBE33D222ZA2B         1   C3
 MD1907201B      STTH810FP              1   D1
 MD1907201B      031201.5MXP            1   F1
 MD1907201B      HSS-B20-NP-12          2   Heatsink
 MD1907201B      92005A114              2   M3 Heasink Screw
 MD1907201B      90592A085              2   M3 Heatsink Nut
 MD1907201B      HF115AC-0.0055-AC-54   2   Thermal Pad
 MD1907201B      90272A144              4   6-32 Screw
 MD1907201B      7587k431               1   "6"" Red wire"
 MD1907201B      7587k64                1   "6"" Black wire"

 SELECT Dif2.[MD/SA Number], Dif2.[Part Number], Dif2.Quantity, 
 Dif2.Designator
 FROM Dif2 LEFT JOIN Dif1 ON Dif2.[Part Number] = Dif1.[Part Number]
 WHERE (((Dif1.[Part Number]) Is Null));

 MD/SA Number   Part Number      Quantity   Designator
 MD1907201A     R463R410000M1K   2          C1, C2
 MD1907201A     1N4007-TP        1          D1
 MD1907201A     3AG7-R           1          F1
 MD1907201A     FC-102-22        2          F1 (Fuse Holder)
 MD1907201A     634-10ABPE       2          Heatsink
 MD1907201A     90272A143        10         6-32 Screw
 MD1907201A     90272A106        2          4-40 Screw
 MD1907201A     92319A634        4          6-32 Standoff
 MD1907201A     455-1319-1-ND    2          J1 Mating Pins
 MD1907201A     8054T26          1          "6"" Red Wire"
 MD1907201A     8054T26          1          "6"" Black Wire"

 SELECT Dif1.[MD/SA Number], Dif1.[Part Number], Dif1.Quantity, 
 Dif1.Designator
 FROM Dif1 LEFT JOIN Dif2 ON Dif1.[Part Number] = Dif2.[Part Number]
 WHERE (((Dif2.[Part Number]) Is Null))
 UNION ALL SELECT Dif2.[MD/SA Number], Dif2.[Part Number], Dif2.Quantity, 
 Dif2.Designator
 FROM Dif2 LEFT JOIN Dif1 ON Dif2.[Part Number] = Dif1.[Part Number]
 WHERE (((Dif1.[Part Number]) Is Null));

 MD/SA Number   Part Number Quantity    Designator
 MD1907201A     61          2           C1, C2
 MD1907201A     62          1           D1
 MD1907201A     63          1           F1
 MD1907201A     64          2           F1 (Fuse Holder)
 MD1907201A     65          2           Heatsink
 MD1907201A     66          10          6-32 Screw
 MD1907201A     67          2           4-40 Screw
 MD1907201A     68          4           6-32 Standoff
 MD1907201A     69          2           J1 Mating Pins
 MD1907201A     70          1           "6"" Red Wire"
 MD1907201A     70          1           "6"" Black Wire"
 MD1907201B     36          2           C1, C2
 MD1907201B     37          1           C3
 MD1907201B     39          1           D1
 MD1907201B     41          1           F1
 MD1907201B     53          2           Heatsink
 MD1907201B     54          2           M3 Heasink Screw
 MD1907201B     55          2           M3 Heatsink Nut
 MD1907201B     56          2           Thermal Pad
 MD1907201B     57          4           6-32 Screw
 MD1907201B     58          1           "6"" Red wire"
 MD1907201B     59          1           "6"" Black wire"
```

I expected the output to have the actual part numbers under the Part Numbers heading, while I got numbers that do not appear anywhere in my database.

Comment: Please post the query code that you are using.  Results are good, but chances are likely its in the query code itself.

Comment: @Mike I added the only other two queries, the rest of them were already in the question, directly above their results.

Comment: The datasets posted look identical. So where is the issue? If `R463R410000M1K` is not correct what should be? Post example raw data. Are you using lookups in table design?

Comment: Had the wrong one pasted in.

Comment: I see some other posts about Access getting confused with joins involving nulls.  Try adding a *first* query `select "dummy", "dummy", 1, "dummy" from Dif1 where false` and `union` all with your final query, to coerce the column types

Comment: Is the part number field a memo field?  Memo fields behave strangely across the board in my experience.  Try doing something like `LEFT(Dif1.[Part Number],10) as [Part Number]`